# jQuery-UI draggable stack and handle together

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```
$(function() {
$("#set div").draggable({ stack: { group: '#set div', min: 1 } handle: 'p.handler2' });
    });
```

anywhere wrong?

Comment: You need a comma between attribute declarations, `stack` and `handle`, not sure if that's the entire issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a comma between attribute declarations, `stack` and `handle`.

```
$(function() {
  $("#set div").draggable({ stack: { group: '#set div', min: 1 }, handle: 'p.handler2' });
});
```

*(Converted to answer so this can be taken off the unanswered list)*